# Find the mean and the variance of $X(1)$ for stochastic differential equation: $dX(t)=-1.5X(t)dt+0.85dW(t)$ with $X(0)=0.7$

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-calculus, variance, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that $X(t)$ satisfies

$\hspace{5cm}$
$dX(t)=-1.5X(t)dt+0.85dW(t)$

with $X(0)=0.7.$ Find the mean and the variance of $X(1).$

---

I know that $E[X(1)]$ will result in mean and $E[(X(1))^{2}]$ in variance. I am not sure how to calculate it. Can I use Ito's formula or some other method will used to solve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apply Ito to $y=f(x)=x^2$ to get for $Y_t=f(X_t)$ the SDE $$dY_t=a(t,Y_t)\,dt+b(t,Y_t)\,dW_t.$$ Then with $\mu_1(t)=E[X_t]$ and $\mu_2(t)=E[X_t^2]$ you should be able to justify the differential equations
$$
\mu_1'(t)=-1.5\mu_1(t)\\
\mu_2'(t)=a(t,\mu_2(t))
$$
where the $t$-dependence of $a$ can include terms with $\mu_1(t)$. Note that the variance of $X_t$ is $\mu_2(t)-\mu_1(t)^2$.

Comment: I have found $E[X(1)]=0.7e^{-1.5}$ and $Var(X(1))= 0.85^2\left(\frac{1}{-3}e^{-3}-1 \right) + 0.7^{2} e^{-3}$. It it correct or I have made a mistake?

Comment: With $dX_t=-rX_t\,dt + σ\,dW_t$ you get $$dY_t=2X_t\,dX_t+σ^2\,dt=(-2rY_t+σ^2)\,dt+2σX_t\,dW_t.$$ So for the variance $v(t)$ you get $$v'(t)=-2r\mu_2(t)+σ^2+2r\mu_1(t)^2=-2rv(t)+σ^2$$ with $v(0)=0$. Thus $$v(t)=\frac{σ^2}{2r}(1-e^{-2rt}).$$ This looks similar, but not equal to your result. The terms with the initial value $x_0$ should cancel.

Comment: What about the $E[X(1)]?$ Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This is my approach to finding variance. I have put the values of $\alpha = -1.5$, $\sigma=0.85$, $X_0=0.7$ at end and got answer I showed previously. why does both answers of yours and mine doesn't match? If you Could help me resolve this confusion that will be great. Where am I making a mistake?   \begin{align*}
E\left(X_t^2\right) &= E\left(\left(X_t-E(X_t)\right)^2\right) + \left(E\left(X_t\right) \right)^2\\
&=\sigma^2 \int_0^te^{2\alpha(t-s)} ds + X_0^2 e^{2\alpha t}\\
&=\sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha} e^{2\alpha t}-1 \right) + X_0^2 e^{2\alpha t}.
\end{align*}

Comment: What exactly did you insert as $X_t-E[X_t]$? This would need the full solution of the SDE, but you have apparently done that correctly behind the scenes. The evaluation of the integral is wrong, you should get the denominator $2α$ outside the parenthesis, $-\frac{σ^2}{2α}[e^{2α(t-s)}]_{s=0}^{s=t}$. Note again that the variance is $Var(X_t)=E[(X_t-E[X_t])^2]=E[X_t^2]-E[X_t]^2$.